# Does an Sql server Insert request wait for the Insert Trigger to complete?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

If I make a request from my application to insert a row and the table has an insert trigger., Does my application request wait for the trigger also to complete or will it just return me the value once the insert is completed??

Comment: It waits for the trigger to complete.

Comment: I believe execution of the trigger behaves internally as if it's part of the same transaction as the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with comments.  If you manually run an insert statement on a table with an insert trigger that then updates another row, it will return rows affected for both your own row and the row the trigger updated.

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```